# How to change rancher single-install cert from self-signed cert to signed by CA cert

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes

How to change rancher single-install cert from self-signed cert to signed by CA cert?

I tried to backup the rancher container and created a new one with `--no-cacerts`.
All the data seems gone. Afterwards, I created new admin account and tried to remove all the data in `/var/lib/rancher/` and re-restore data again. The container log says that rancher is:

```
[INFO] waiting for server to become available: Get https://localhost:6443/version?timeout=30s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I doubt that there're some information embedded in the rancher data directory (`/var/lib/rancher/`) and it contains the original self-signed cert.

Is there a good way to safely change certification?

Comment: Note: rotating the cluster certs is not helping since it just sign another self assigned one and restarts all the system pods.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to your problem but, starting with Rancher 2.0, Rancher have built-in support for Lets Encrypt certificates. The only parameter needed to enable this, is `--acme-domain rancher.yourdomain.com`. It will use the http-01 challenge to verify, so make sure port 80 is open from the container.